# Library install path for boost

Tags: c++, boost

I would like to install boost in windows 10 using visual studio 2017 with the following directory structure:

```
boost-1.65.0/
├── include/
│   
├── lib/
│   ├── Debug
│   └── Release
└──
```

From the source directory of boost, I have tried

```
bootstrap.bat
b2 -j8 toolset=msvc-14.1 address-model=64 link=static --build-type=minimal variant=debug --prefix=C:\install\boost_1.65.0
```

Is there any option that I could pass to b2 like `install-lib=C:\install\boost_1.65.0\lib\Debug`. Any help would be much appreciated.
Thanks.